# How do I add two columns with different rows with special condition?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

Hi I have a **PySpark dataframe**. So, I would like to add two columns from different rows with special condition. One of the columns is a date type.

Here is the example of the data:

```
--------------------------------
| flag|      date     |  diff  |
--------------------------------
| 1   |   2014-05-31  | 0      |
--------------------------------
| 2   |   2014-06-02  | 2      |
--------------------------------
| 3   |   2016-01-14  | 591    |
--------------------------------
| 1   |   2016-07-08  | 0      |
--------------------------------
| 2   |   2016-07-12  | 4      |
--------------------------------
```

Currently I only know how to add the two columns, by using this code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
dataframe.withColumn("new_column", expr("date_add(date_column, int_column)"))
```

**The expected result**:

There's a new Column, called "new_date" which is a result by adding the "diff" column to "date column".

The catch is there's a special condition: if the "flag" is 1, "date" and "diff" come from the same row, **if not, the "date" comes from the previous row**.

I am aware that in this scenario, my data has to be correctly sorted.

If anyone could help me, I would be very grateful. Thank you.

Comment: is it always the case that diff is 0 when flag is 1?

Comment: @gaw unfortunately no

Comment: what should happen in your first row? there is no previous date and should the `diff` be added to the previous date in case `flag` is set to `1`? or should just the previous date be in the `new_date` column

Comment: @gaw the first row will always have the "flag" value as 1. if the "flag" value is 1, the addition of "date" and "diff" come from the same row. To make it clear, "flag" means like the n-th time of a usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to create a column with the previous date using Window and construct the new column depending on the value of 'flag'

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window().partitionBy().orderBy(F.col('date'))

dataframe = dataframe.withColumn('previous_date', F.lag('date', 1).over(w))

dataframe = dataframe.withColumn('new_date',
                                 F.when(F.col('flag')==1,
                                        F.expr("date_add(previous_date, diff)")
                                        ).otherwise(F.expr("date_add(date, diff)"))
                                ).drop('previous_date')
```

Comment: you can replace `dataframe = dataframe.withColumn('previous_date', F.lag('date', 1).over(w))` and the test with `dataframe = dataframe.withColumn('previous_date', F.coalesce(F.lag('date').over(w), F.col("date"))`. No need to use `when` after.

Comment: You can't because there will always be the previous date in your column (excluding the first row). You can't get get away without conditioning on the value of 'flag' at one point or another from what I understand.

Comment: yes, @XavierCanton is right. I will try your answer. Hope it could fix my problem.

Comment: I think you have some syntax issue here. The brackets do not fully match if I'm not mistaken. And in my environment the `date_add` function does not directly work on columns. but maybe its an issue of the environment

Comment: You're right, there is a a missing bracket, I will edit my answer. Same for the date_add, I will edit using expr instead

Comment: @XavierCanton it worked!! thank you very much for the answer. although, the 'condition' actually should be switched. again, thank you!

Comment: @XavierCanton indeed. I missed that part. My bad :)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you have the same issue with the answer of Xavier. The idea is the same, but I removed some unnecessary conditions for the Window and fixed the syntax error, as well as the `date_add` error I faced, when I tried his version.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1,datetime.date(2014,5,31),0),(2,datetime.date(2014,6,2),2),(3,datetime.date(2016,1,14),591),(1,datetime.date(2016,7,8),0),(2,datetime.date(2016,7,12),4)], ["flag","date","diff"])

w = Window.orderBy(col("date"))
df1 = df1.withColumn('previous_date', lag('date', 1).over(w))
df1 = df1.withColumn('new_date',when(col('flag')==1,\
expr('date_add(date, diff)'))\
.otherwise(expr('date_add(previous_date,diff)'))).drop('previous_date')
df1.show()
```

Output:

```python
+----+----------+----+----------+
|flag|      date|diff|  new_date|
+----+----------+----+----------+
|   1|2014-05-31|   0|2014-05-31|
|   2|2014-06-02|   2|2014-06-02|
|   3|2016-01-14| 591|2016-01-14|
|   1|2016-07-08|   0|2016-07-08|
|   2|2016-07-12|   4|2016-07-12|
+----+----------+----+----------+
```

Comment: feel free to upvote helpful answers and mark the correct one, to show this question as answered

Comment: yeah I can't do that, my reputation is still below 15. Will do that once I'm eligible.